# Find next control in LostFocus event?

Tags: ms-access

Short form: In MS Access VBA (2010), I would like to know which control is about to get the focus during a LostFocus event.

Long form:
In a form I have a subform which contains a list of fruits, numbers and a comment. In the form, I display that subform in list view for a previously known set of fruits:

```
Fruit    Count    Comment
Apples
Apples
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
Bananas
```

The user enters counts for each fruit:

```
Fruit    Count    Comment
Apples   4
Apples   3
Apples   2
Oranges  5
Bananas  2
Bananas  -1         ( = rotten)
```

Now I need to calculate averages like this:

```
Fruit    Count    Comment
Apples   4
Apples   3
Apples   2
Apples   3        Average
Oranges  5
Bananas  2
Bananas  -1
Bananas  -1       Average
```

I already have a Sub which does that, but it's too slow to run it after each input. It also confuses the user that suddenly some averages appear among her inputs. So I want to run it only after the user is finished entering counts.

The IMO natural place to run this average calculation would be the LostFocus event of the count control, but only if the focus changes to something else than another count control. How can I do that (screen.ActiveControl is no help because during LostFocus it's still the old control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a variable to store the last control you were in.
`dim LastUsedControl as string`

On your `LostFocus` event for your count field
`LastUsedControl = Me.ActiveControl.Name`

Using the `OnEnter` event of your other fields you could do

```
If LastUsedControl = "txtCount" then
    Call FindAverageCount
End If
```

Then create a method that calculates and updates your records with averages `public sub FindAverageCount()` and then call then in the `OnEnter` event only if you came from editing the count field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It involves writing OnEnter handlers for all other controls. I can achieve the same thing with GetFocus on all other controls and LostFocus on the subform. I was looking for a way to do this without writing 8 extra event handlers, but it seems that's impossible

Comment: Is it really not possible to do what @batox is describing, though? Reference the name of the new control/next active control within the LostFocus event of the (soon-to-be) PreviousControl? The accepted answer doesn't appear to definitively state whether or not this is possible.